# The measurable function $\xi$ is with value of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I have a problem I don't understand, in the following lemma:

[image]

In the proof of the lemma, the function $\xi$ is with value in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. But in the statement of the lemma, the measurable function  $\xi$ is with value of $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: I don't think so. Measurable functions can have $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ as co-domain.

Comment: The same also for the sequence $\{\xi_n\}$?

Comment: Let $\xi_n$ be the a.s. constant function with value $n$. Clearly, the lemma only works in this case if $\xi$ is a.s. constant with value $\infty$.